# Ajax Notification system - using latest notification_id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

So I have the majority of my system working and I am stuck on one last bit

The GET is currentlyusing the same notification_id it gets from the while loop, so it constantly searches against that id for new records over and over.

LIKE SO...

```
jquery....4862996 (line 4)
GET http://viewajax.php?notification_id=43&_=1405814864693


jquery....4862996 (line 4)
GET http://viewajax.php?notification_id=43&_=1405814864694
```

What I'm looking to do is search the first notification_id from the while loop send it off to the server side viewajax.php to see if there is a new record and if there is insert it into its div, (which it currently does) but then use that same new notification_id from the server on its next ajax cycle for new records. I've tried everything and asked many questions and I've been looking high and low online for possible solutions to no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated and I will love you forever.

AJAX

```
<?  
$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
$call="select * from notifications WHERE notification_targetuser='$user1_id' AND notification_status=1 ORDER BY notification_id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $chant=mysqli_query($mysqli,$call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

while($notification=mysqli_fetch_array($chant)){
            ?>
             <script type="text/javascript">

function loadIt() {

  var notification_id=<?php echo $notification['notification_id'] ;?>

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id,   
dataType:"json",
cache: false,
success: function(data){
 $("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id).prepend('<div class="notif_ui"><div class="notif_text"><div  id="notif_actual_text-'+data['notification_id']+'" class="notif_actual_text"><img border=\"1\" src=\"userimages/cropped'+data['notification_triggeredby']+'.jpg\" onerror=this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ><br /><a href="'+data['notification_id']+'">'+data['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+data['notification_time']+'<br /></div></div></div></div>');
 i = parseInt($("#mes").text()); $("#mes").text((i+data.num)); 
}
});
}
setInterval(loadIt, 10000);                        
          </script>


<? }}?>
```

VIEWAJAX.php

```
if(isset($_GET['notification_id'])){

$id= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_GET['notification_id']);
$user1_id= $_SESSION['id'];
$json = array();
$com=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select notification_id,notification_content,notification_time,notification_triggeredby from notifications where notification_id > '$id' AND notification_status='1' ");
echo mysqli_error($mysqli);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($com);
if($num>0){

    $json['num'] = $num;
}else{
    $json['num'] = 0;
}
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($com);
$json['notification_id'] = $resultArr['notification_id'];
$json['notification_content'] = $resultArr['notification_content'];
$json['notification_triggeredby'] = $resultArr['notification_triggeredby'];
$json['notification_time'] = $resultArr['notification_time'];
mysqli_free_result($com);

echo json_encode($json);

}
```

EDIT

PHP SOURCE

```
{"num":0,"notification_id":null,"notification_content":null,"notification_triggeredby":null,"notification_time":null}
```

AJAX SOURCE

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

function loadIt() {


  var notification_id=44
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id,   
dataType:"json",
cache: false,
success: function(data){
 $("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id).prepend('<div class="notif_ui"><div class="notif_text"><div  id="notif_actual_text-'+data['notification_id']+'" class="notif_actual_text"><img border=\"1\" src=\"userimages/cropped'+data['notification_triggeredby']+'.jpg\" onerror=this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ><br /><a href="'+data['notification_id']+'">'+data['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+data['notification_time']+'<br /></div></div></div></div>');
 i = parseInt($("#mes").text()); $("#mes").text((i+data.num)); 
}
});
}
setInterval(loadIt, 10000);              



          </script>
```

Comment: You're a lot more likely to get help with the javascript end of things if you post properly indented code and post what the browser sees (use View/Source in the browser), not your PHP template file.  As it stands now, I have no idea what the JS actually looks like because I don't know exactly what your PHP embedded in the template is going to do.  If you post what the browser sees, then that is no longer a problem.

Comment: Also not clear at all what your specific problem is.

Comment: Everytime Ajax fires it fires from the last_id in the database from the while loop on the clientside.. it passes that id to the server side and searches for new records. Say there is a new record it comes back and inserts it into a div. Then restarts the aax process again, only with the same id it searched the database with the first time around.. that new id it just found, I need to use that one to search with so there is a constant loop of new data.

Comment: I can't use the same notification_id to search for new data.. because anything after that will always be printed out again and again. I need to always search for new data by id and always have fresh data.

Comment: I need to somehow use the data.notification_id as that will be the new id on the next interval.

Comment: get the last id inserted and send that back with data, then update variable when it arrives

Comment: How would I go about doing that tho, that is where I'm confused?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just update "notification_status" to 0 after you retrieve it in the php parts? Then it will not be retrieved again.